# JavaScript and Angular callbacks

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, callback

Good afternoon.

I'm currently developing an Angular15 app and I'm using a .js file that contains certain functions that I need to use in my project.
I'm being able to use these functions but I have reached a point where I don't know how to continue because I have found a problem that I don't know if it has a solution and in case of having it, I don't know it:

I have to use a function of this .js file. This function makes a call to certain endpoint and when the call finish, it can return an OK or an error.
The function expects 2 parameters: a callback function for the OK and another callback function for the error. These callbacks functions must be implemented by me and depending on which callback is executed, the function sends certain data to that callback.

For example, if the callback for the OK is executed, the callback will receive a string with a base64 content. If the callback for the error is executed, then the callback will receive a string with the error type and another string with the error message.

I have this code in a .ts file:

```
makeCall() {
this.JSLibrary.call(() => {this.callbackOK()}, () => {this.callbackError()});
}

callBackOK() {
console.log('OK');
}

callbackError() {
console.log('ERROR');
}
```

As you can see, I have defined both callbacks function to just simply do a console.log, and the method makeCall will use the function call of the JS file.

The problem is: I don't know how to pass the information that the JSLibrary.call method will send to each callback because if I define the parameters in the callback functions, then the typescript compiler will say that I'm not passing those parameters in the JSLibrary.call function:

```
callBackOK(base64: string) {
console.log(base64);
}

callbackError(errorType: string, errorMessage: string) {
console.log('ERROR': + errorType + errorMessage);
}

makeCall() {
this.JSLibrary.call(() => {this.callbackOK()}, () => {this.callbackError()});
}
ERROR BECAUSE I'M NOT PASSING THE PARAMETERS UP HERE
```

So, the question is: Is there any way to pass the information to each callback?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arguments` variable is a kind of built-in feature of functions in JavaScript and TypeScript, which behaves like an array and holds all the values passed into the function.

You don't have to name the arguments or define them in advance. You can simply retroactively access them via the `arguments` object. This is especially useful when you need to know how many arguments will be passed in, like in your case with the callbacks.

However, due to the improvements in ES6 (ECMAScript 6) and further, it's better to use rest parameters `...args` in many cases. They work similarly but behave like real arrays and have more features. For example, you can use forEach and other Array methods on them.

Here is another way to define your `makeCall` function:

```
makeCall() {
    this.JSLibrary.call((...args) => {this.callbackOK(...args)}, (...args) => {this.callbackError(...args)});
}

callbackOK(base64: string) {
  console.log(base64);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is an appropriate way of handling the issue. However, it's worth considering writing a type declaration which describes the shape of the library's API.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Your solution worked almost perfectly: 

I was able to use ...args and pass that in makeCall() function, but in the callbackOK function I have to use ...args also, because if I use base64: string, I receive an error telling me that I need to pass base64 parameter in makeCall():
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter